# Can't change the image button inside the datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I would like to know if is it possible to change the image button inside the datagridview based on a certain condition? I would like to change the image of the button inside the datagridview based on the value of status. If the status of is active i like to change it to green dot and if it not(inactive) i change it to red dot
Here is my code:

```
If dgridPatient.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name = "btnStatus" AndAlso e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            Try
                If dgridPatient.Rows.Count >= 1 Then
                    For i As Integer = 0 To dgridPatient.Rows.Count
                        'If Not IsDBNull(dgridPatient.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value) _
                        '       AndAlso dgridPatient.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value.Equals("Active") Then
                        If (dgridPatient.Rows(i).Cells("Status").Value.ToString = "Inactive") Then
                            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All)
                            e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.icons8_Filled_Circle_3, CInt((e.CellBounds.Width / 2) - (My.Resources.icons8_Filled_Circle_3.Width / 2)) + e.CellBounds.X, CInt((e.CellBounds.Height / 2) - (My.Resources.icons8_Filled_Circle_3.Height / 2)) + e.CellBounds.Y)
                            e.Handled = True

                    Else
                        e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.All)
                        e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.icons8_Filled_Circle_5, CInt((e.CellBounds.Width / 2) - (My.Resources.icons8_Filled_Circle_5.Width / 2)) + e.CellBounds.X, CInt((e.CellBounds.Height / 2) - (My.Resources.icons8_Filled_Circle_5.Height / 2)) + e.CellBounds.Y)
                        e.Handled = True
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString)
        End Try
    End If
```

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF (I'm assuming not WebForms since you're using e.Graphics).  Also, what is the context when this code runs?  There's not enough information here to accurately respond.

Comment: Sorry sir , the codes works fine but it change all the button image based on the last entry of the database. Example i have an entry in my table which the status is set in active and the second entry set to in inactive it changes the button image but set on the last entry which is inactive.

Comment: It is developed in winforms sir ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no Image button natively in Datagridview button.
But you can read the last two posts here
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f7f4fa33-5aed-4074-a4cd-ebf43dd8362c/image-button-in-datagridview?forum=vbgeneral

This way you can put different images for active or inactive